UFT Test case Execution triggered form Jenkins over vdi _getting stopped when we switch off or log off from computer
My Jenkins server is at emea account, and vdi also at emea account.
But I access both of them from my asia specific laptop(bank provided).
When I trigger the jenkins job to execute UFT scripts on vdi, if my system is locked but connected to network execution works fine.
If I switch off or log off from my computer to come home, execution goes on hold
Execution should not stop since its triggered via jenkins on vdi
